# How can add data on WillPopScope

Tags: flutter, dart

I want add data at all 'pop'

It two case,
Android back key and some button for '`navigator.(context).pop()`'

So I used WillPopScope but I can't add data like this

```
onWillPop: () async {
        return Navigator.of(context).pop(myData));
      },
```

this is not working.

How can I add data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(myData)
```

in your code, the `pop` with arguments will be delivered if `onWillPop` return `true`.

When popping a page, `onWillPop` has the duty to day "ok you can pop" or "ok you cannot".